# MS Word Compare not showing changes

Tags: microsoft-word, comparison

I recently changed from a computer running Windows 10 Pro 64 with Office 2019 Pro to Windows 11 Pro 64 with Office LTSC Pro Plus 2021.

Today, for the first time since that change, I tried using MS Word compare, and it's not working.

To boil down the problem, I created two files that contain only the text, "Version 1" in one file and "Version 2" in the other. Then I asked Word to compare those files:

[image: MS Compare dialog box without section for setting markup colors]

The first thing I notice is that there seems to be something missing from that dialog box. It used to have a section that allowed me to set the colors of the markup, and that's not there.

I click OK in that box and get:

[image: MS Compare not showing changes]

The problem is in the middle pane, "Compared Document". It should say:

[image: What MS Compare should be saying]

indicating that the "1" was deleted and the "2" added.

I looked around in the menus for compare settings, including under "File > Options", and didn't find any. Googling the problem, I found a couple of places that told me to change a setting under the "Tools" menu, but as you can see above, there is no such menu now.

I also found the suggestion to change "Review > Tracking > Simple Markup" to "Review > Tracking > Full Markup". I did that, and it didn't fix the problem. But I also noticed that after trying that, when I went back to "Review > Tracking", it was again showing "Simple Markup", so it seems that that change did not stick.

I found a setting under "Review > Tracking > Show Markup > Balloons" that was set to "Show Only Comments and Formatting in Balloons". I changed that to "Show All Revisions Inline". That change stuck, but did not fix the problem.

The locations of those two menu settings are:

[image: MS Word menu settings for Tracking]

You can see from the menus above that I also have Adobe Acrobat installed. The final part of the problem occurs when I make a pdf of the comparison using "Acrobat > Create PDF". In the second display image above, in the "Compared Document" pane, you see a red vertical bar in the left margin indicating that there is a change on that line. Previously, that red bar also appears in the pdf I made of a comparison, but it is not here:

[image: No red bar in pdf of MS Word comparison]

The result of all the above is that I am getting no information about changes in my file. What do I need to do to get that information back?

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem with Word Pro Plus 2021 but I appear to have found a work around.  Once you have done the comparison there is a red line on the left to indicate that changes have been made but there is no indication of what the changes are.  If you go into 'View' the ribbon shows that it is in 'Print Layout'  If you change this to 'Draft' the deletions and additions are shown and if you then change back to 'Print Layout' they continue to be shown.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hmm, this is strange. I went back and repeated the steps in my question, and this time, Word showed the change in the middle pane without me doing anything extra. So that looked good to start with. But when I saved to a pdf, the changes were not shown. Since the pdf is the way I've been keeping a record of changes, the process is useless without that. Ugh!